# Input type="number" is not working with currency pipe

Tags: javascript, angular

Currency pipe is not working for `input` type number and I did not get any value in web page. I found several blog and understand that currency pipe works with input type text but my requirement strict with number. Is there way to use `input` type number with currency pipe.

```
<input type="number" name="totalCompensation"  [(ngModel)]="model.totalCompensation | currency:'USD':true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Input type number allows only integers, and floating numbers including optional characters '.', 'e' or 'E' and '+' or '-'

See details in specs:

https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/input.number.html

https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/datatypes.html#common.data.float